Typescript: RXJS `distinctUntilChanged` not working with strict / first parameter undefined
The following code doesn't work:
let observable: Observable<{ key: number }> = of({ key: 123 });
observable.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(undefined, v => v.key)
);

Although there is an overload:
export function distinctUntilChanged<T, K>(
  comparator?: (previous: K, current: K) => boolean,
  keySelector: (value: T) => K = identity as (value: T) => K
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>

What's the reason for it?

The example provided, is not a TypeScript example, so undefined is not allowed in the below types as a first argument! instead just specify a default comparator and set the keySelector!
Type Definition:
import { MonoTypeOperatorFunction } from '../types';
export declare function distinctUntilChanged<T>(comparator?: (previous: T, current: T) => boolean): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
export declare function distinctUntilChanged<T, K>(comparator: (previous: K, current: K) => boolean, keySelector: (value: T) => K): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;

Code:
import { of, distinctUntilChanged, Observable } from 'rxjs';
export interface TypeObj {
  updatedBy: string;
  data: Array<string>;
}
// A stream of updates to a given account
const accountUpdates$: Observable<TypeObj> = of(
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'ncjamieson', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'ncjamieson', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] }
);

// We only want the events where it changed hands
const changedHands$ = accountUpdates$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged<TypeObj, string>(
    (prev: string, curr: string): boolean => prev === curr,
    (update: TypeObj) => update?.updatedBy
  )
);

changedHands$.subscribe(console.log);

Stackblitz Demo

Sure this works! But why doesn't their default implementation? Isn't that totally valid? https://stackblitz.com/run?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts

@tris it works for me stackblitz I took the docs from here docs, notice there is not tsconfig.json in their example so undefined is allowed! Your example link doesnt work for me!

@tris without tsconfig.json typescript isn't configured!

Thank you for mentioning! :) But still I don't get why their code wouldn't work in strict mode? The overload I mentioned has an optional comparator? - so why wouldn't I be able to just pass "undefined"?

@tris Could you share the version of rxjs, because in my example, there is no ?: for the comparator!

Sure! Using the latest one (7.8.1) with the overload I've posted in my initial post. Here is the file from the repo: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/9c8fa65ea161f97cc90ea9b4679b0ae104a29ffb/packages/rxjs/src/internal/operators/distinctUntilChanged.ts#L138

@tris Looks like a bug to me, please raise a github issue that the type is not exported! stackblitz The definition is there, but its not present in the types of node_modules! do let me know I will raise if needed!

Are you sure it isn't? I can find this definition:
export function distinctUntilChanged<T, K>(   comparator?: (previous: K, current: K) => boolean,   keySelector: (value: T) => K = identity as (value: T) => K ): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>
Maybe I just don't match the keySelector: (value: T) => K = identity as (value: T) => K? The regular keySelector looks different: keySelector: (value: T) => K

@tris Yes as far as I know its not there, I checked distinctUntilChanged.d.ts

Isn't this the place to check: node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\operators\distinctUntilChanged.ts? Just scroll down, it is below the comments. Looks like it was added afterwards.

@tris check inside node_modules, after you do an install of rxjs, there I didnt find it, what you are showing is source code, not compiled code!

Checked node_modules but not dist! You're totally right, ty! :)
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/7475

Actually, you are misusing distinctUntilChanged
Refactor your code like below and it should be OK :
const observable: Observable<{ key: number }> = of({ key: 123 });
observable.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.key === curr.key)
);


The docs say you can use a key selector only (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged). And so looks the definition I've posted.
